# Chat system in our SharePoint Online - Office 365

Tags: office-365, chart-web-part

I am looking for an add-in that will allow us to have in browser chat capability. My company will not go for skype for busines, and I checked Groups functionality in Office 365, but it doesn't provide instant messaging. I am looking if this was already developed or we should do it ourselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked Yammer? You can associate Yammer with your Office365 organization and have a communication system there (chat, newsfeeds, etc..)

Comment: can we connect to it with our office 365?

Comment: Yes, it will create a network for your Office 365 where you can communicate with only people within your organization. You can also create public groups where you can invite other people from outside as well which makes it powerful. You should try it out.